# how to examine which forms were added, changed or deleted in django

Tags: django, formset

I have a usecase where a models may not be changed after it has been saved for the first time, but additions, changes and deletions must be logged (in another model).

In the docs i found the `formset.deleted_forms` variable which gives me the deleted forms. Further i could be able to find the changed forms in a formset with the `form.has_changed()` method. An approach for for finding the number of added forms is to calculate the difference of TOTAL-FORMS and INITIAL-FORMS but i still dont know which forms were added.

What i exactly need is a diff of a models instance (and foreign key set) before and after a formset has been submit. How can I achieve that?

I appreciate every kind of hint or help

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

Just regocnized that formset.extra_forms will contain the added forms even if the number of initial extra forms is zero.